# USB Boot doesn't work with raspberry pi 2

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

I recently received a raspberry pi 2 from my neighbor. I already have a rasperry pi 3 in use myself for my HomeAssistant. For HomeAssistant I use a 16GB usb. On the raspberry pi 2 i want to install raspbian. I wanted to use a 16GB usb for this too, but it doesn't work. I used the official installation of raspbian. I have tried all USB ports, but none of them work for a boot of raspian (Ubuntu does not work to boot either). I have also used an sd card and that works. Whilst in raspbian I checked all the usb ports and all of them seems to be working. But because the sd card got corrupted it was stuck in a boot loop.
Therefore I want to use a USB.

My question is: why doesn't the Bootable USB work and how can I get it working?

Comment: Because Pi2 doesn't support USB boot.

Comment: Even if that question would be answered easily by reading the documentation and googling this still remains a valid question IMO he also described his efforts. I cannot see why this is being downvoted

Comment: By the way, the Pi 2 v1.2 **can** boot from USB - so, saying the Pi2 doesn't support USB boot is almost correct - you just need to [enable it](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#raspberry-pi-2b-3a-3b-cm-3-3-zero-2) - so, check what revision the Pi2 is before blindly accepting that it won't work, you may be lucky and have one that will

Comment: You can only boot an original RPi 2 from an SDCard. You can have the root filesystem stored on a USB stick. There aren't any that will boot from a USB only, that started with the RPi 3 (and the early RPi 3s needed the OTP flag set to allow USB booting).

Comment: @Dougie Your flag got declined without me being able to add a comment (sorry whoops).  Anyway, it does seem that the "2B v1.2" can boot from USB according to [the official docs](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#usb-mass-storage-boot); it follows the process you describe for the Pi 3 (first you need to set the OTP flag...).

Comment: That's why I said "original RPi 2". @goldilocks

Comment: But your flag from several days ago (on Bravo's previous comment about the "Pi 2 v1.2") was, verbatim: *It's wrong. You cannot boot a Pi2 from USB without an SDCard.*  So misquotes all round then ;|

Comment: Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

Answer (score 1):

As @Milliways already stated PI2 doesn't support USB boot. **BUT** you also asked for a additional solution.

You could use a SD Card instead here are my following steps which worked for me with Windows:

1. Download a Bootloader https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware the bootloader contains a file named

> bootcode.bin

2. Format your SD-Card with FAT32 **Important** the filessystem must be **FAT(Standard)**
3. Copy your bootcode.bin into your freshly formatted SD-Card
4. Stick your SD-Card into your Raspberry PI2 and you are Ready to Go

Comment: It may be useful to add that some Pi 2, i.e v1.2, can boot from USB, you just need to enable it (like you do with the Pi 3)

Comment: Very helpful infromation i wil keep that in mind

Comment: WRT to this, to figure out if you have a Pi 2 v1.2, check the last line of output from `/proc/cpuinfo`.

Comment: Thank you! I also had to remove other USB devices than the USB stick. I had a wireless keyboard receiver that caused problems. I realized later that if I changed in which USB ports the drive and the receiver were plugged in, it worked.